# Spring Cloud Gateway: get "Connection has been closed BEFORE response, while sending request body" error when post large file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I have spring boot application running behind a spring cloud gateway.

spring boot application Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "hi")
public String postHi(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletRequest request) {
  return request.getHeader("Content-Length");
}
```

Spring cloud gateway route configuration :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: hi
          uri: http://localhost:8080/hi
          predicates:
            - Path=/hi/**
```

So when I upload small file (size:1000 KB) via a postman request I get no error but when the file is large (size :10 MO) I get the following error :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-12-10T20:52:33.554+0000",
    "path": "/hi",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Connection has been closed BEFORE response, while sending request body",
    "requestId": "ad589017"
}
```

with this stack :

```
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection has been closed BEFORE response, while sending request body
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/hi" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
```

Here is an example to reproduce the issue :
https://github.com/jemmali-git/examples.git

Comment: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/934